# Update a Profile picture

Tags: python, django

so i'm working on little django application where users can view and modify there profile ,but i didn't know how to provide a button under the profile picture that allows the user to choose a new one and when he chooses it redirect him to the same page with the new profile picture ,any help or ideas will be usefull , tnks !! 
here's what i tried :

forms.py

```
class picture_form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Profile
    fields=('image',)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = picture_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        profile.save()
        return redirect(reverse('profile'))



else:
 for usr in User.objects.all():
    if request.user.get_full_name() == usr.get_full_name():
        prf = Profile.objects.filter(user=usr)
        form = picture_form()
        return render(request, 'store/profile.html', {'profile': prf, 'form': form})
```

template

```
   {% if prf.image %}

            <div class="profile-img">
                <img src="{{ prf.image.url }}" id="prf_img" alt=""/>

            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="profile-img">
                <img src="{% static 'img/empty-profile-picture.png' %}" id="prf_img" alt=""/>

            </div>
            {% endif %}

            <!--<a href="{% url 'upload_picture' %}">  <div class="file btn btn-lg " >
                Change Photo
                   <input type="file" name="file"/>
               </div></a> -->
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'profile' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="upload">

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check out [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ImageField), and more generally the documentation on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: @KirollosMorkos my problem is not how to upload file but to do this in the same page without creating another html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has an awesome generic editing view called [**UpdateView**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). You can do something like this:

#### models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

#### views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['image']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = ''

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

#### profile_update_form.html

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

#### urls.py

```
from . import views
path('<int:pk>/update/', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='profile-update')
```